# Need help targeting a sharepoint column to change width

Tags: css, sharepoint-2013, column-width

I want to change the max-width of a column in a sharepoint list view. For some reason this will work for increasing the column which is a multiline text field but not decrease it.

here is what I have tried

```
<style type='text/css'>
td.ms-vb2[DisplayName="Current Issue or Update"]
{
max-width:100px !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a multiline text field, please set the style for the class start with "ExternalClass" using Jquery below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("[class*='ExternalClass']").css('max-width', '50px');
});
</script>
```

[image]